# Скрытый метод вызываемый внутри класса почему-то выводит на печать self, хотя я его и не передавал

Tags: python, методы, print

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

```py
class A:

    def __метод_2(*args):
        print(*args)

    def метод_1(self, *args):
        self.__метод_2(*args)


obj = A()
obj.метод_1('привет')
```

Хочу снаружи запустить , `метод_1` класса и передать ему ряд аргументов.

В свою очередь `метод_1` должен обратиться к другому, в моём случае скрытому методу `__метод_2`, в этом же классе, и допустим вывести полученные аргументы на печать.

Чтобы обратиться к `__метод_2`, мне естественно приходится обратиться к нему через `self` - `self.__метод_2(*args)`, и "О ЧУДО!", кроме переданных аргументов на печать выводится и `self`.

> <**main**.A object at 0x020FEB08> привет

**Не могу понять как это работает и как исправить.**

Comment: "`self`" автоматически передается первым аргументом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте **методу 2** аргумент **self**

```
class A:

    def method2(self, *args): # <---
        print(*args)

    def method1(self, *args):
        self.method2(*args)


obj = A()
obj.method1('привет')
```

**UPD**

Как правильно заметил @n1tr0xs, аргумент передаётся автоматически.
Так что ещё как вариант - выводить только аргумент с индексом **[1]**, игнорируя индекс **[0]**

```
class A:
    def method2(*args):
        print(args[1]) # <--

    def method1(self, *args):
        self.method2(*args)

obj = A()
obj.method1('привет')
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Самое интересное, что я пробовал и `self`, и аргумент с индексом `[1:]`, так как планировал передавать несколько аргументов. И это тоже не работало, как я сейчас понял потому, что работал в `Visual Studio Code` используя `Jupyter Notebooks` , и надо было своевременно очищать кэш.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не взаимодействуете с самим объектом `self` внутри метода и хотите его опустить, то можете воспользоваться встроенным декоратором `@staticmethod`

```py
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def __method1(*args):
        print(*args)

    def method2(self, *args):
        self.__method1(*args)

a = A()
a.method2('привет')
```

Такой статичный метод можно вызывать как у класса `C.f()`, так и экземпляра `C().f()`.